# Redirect to internal URL ignored within facebook app canvas

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, flask, stunnel

I am new to facebook applications, so maybe I am overlooking something very simple.
I am developing this on GAE on flask framework.

This is how I have setup my facebook app. (note the https on localhost is setup through stunnel)
[image]

Everything seems to be ok, until I have to do an internal redirect to the "login".

```
def index(show_friends=None):        
    if current_user.is_authenticated():        
        return redirect(url_for("show_records"))
    if 'fbapp' in request.args:        
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')
```

urls are set like this:

```
app.add_url_rule('/', 'index', view_func=views.index, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
app.add_url_rule('/login', view_func=views.login, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

This fails with the message:

> The connection was reset
>            The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

Looking at the server log, it seems, the login redirect was ignored all together. Not sure why.

```
INFO     2013-07-14 12:15:39,026 dev_appserver.py:3105] "POST /?fbapp HTTP/1.1" 302
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess... But the problem may relay on the fact that the login page sends back an [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) header that disallow the browser to show the page inside the iframe.

If the login page ends up being the appengine login page, well... that page **does** return the `X-Frame-Options` header and cannot be loaded inside the iframe.

If this ends up being the problem, the usual solution is to have the login page loaded on a separate new window that gets automatically closed after a successful login.

Comment: Interestingly you don't even see the `/login` request on the server... but it may just be cached